# How to convert negative datetime.timedelta to positive datetime.timedelta value

Tags: python, date, time, timedelta

so I have multiple time value which I wanna subtract with each other but some of the cases I receive negative timedelta how do I convert it into positive without change the actual value

I tried to use **abs()** but it change the actual value

```
#for example:
time1=timedelta(hours=23,minutes=25,seconds=00)
time2=timedelta(hours=6,minutes=13,seconds=00)

delta_time_value = time2 -time1
print(delta_time_value) #-1 day, 13:01:00 (ANSWER)
```

The result which I was getting is **-1 day, 13:01:00**
but I want the result like this **1 day, 13:01:00**
**without -ve sign**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import timedelta

time1=timedelta(hours=23,minutes=25,seconds=00)
time2=timedelta(hours=6,minutes=13,seconds=00)

delta_time_value = str(time2 - time1)

print(delta_time_value)

if delta_time_value[0] == "-":
  print(delta_time_value[1:])
```

This is a easy fix, not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: No worries, if this is what you are looking for, please accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the positive value, you can use "abs()" but you need to change the value in a float first:

```
time1=timedelta(hours=23,minutes=25,seconds=00)
time2=timedelta(hours=6,minutes=13,seconds=00)

delta_time_value = time2 -time1
print(delta_time_value) # OUTPUT -1 day, 13:01:00

print(delta_time_value.total_seconds()) # OUTPUT -61920.0
print(abs(delta_time_value.total_seconds())) # OUTPUT 61920.0
```

And if you want a string at the end, you just need to do a simple f-string with the value (in 'int' this time):

```
a = int(abs(delta_time_value.total_seconds()))
format = f'{a // 3600}:{(a % 3600) // 60}:{a % 60}0'
print(format) # OUTPUT 17:12:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time1=timedelta(hours=23,minutes=25,seconds=00)
time2=timedelta(hours=6,minutes=13,seconds=00)

print('{}'.format(time2 -time1).replace("-",""))
```

Simple usage of str.replace() should suffice as we are not aware which timedelta would be greater. This would replace the "-" (minus) sign only. Thanks.

Comment: Hi :), your answer seems great, but can use some more explanation. Please have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer  if you need guidance doing so. Thanks